# Trick a second transaction to see same thing with first even if first has made changes

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I have the following two transactions (it's an old exam question that i'm trying to solve). I need without using commit, rollback or insert into
to get the same output in transaction A and B. 
I managed to do this with adding

```
REPLACE INTO T
SELECT 10,10 FROM dual;
```

to the red colored text (marked "(1)")
and it worked but I wonder if there is any other way, like changing isolation level or do something more tricky?
Also, is there any command from transaction B that we can delete it and still get the same results?
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsjO7.png

Comment: Do you need to add something to transaction B where the red line is, or can you add sg anywhere to B? This is not clear ftom your question.

Comment: Also, the exam questionshould specify the isolation level because it can materially affect the results.

Comment: @Shadow We are running on mysql, so it is the default isolation level. We can add only to the red line.

Comment: Mysql does not have a default isolation level, that's applicable on the storage engine level only. E.g. innodb has a default isolation level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment you can only issue the command at the red dotted line. Based on your comment I also assume that innodb table engine is used with the default repeatable read isolation mode.

The above means that changing the transaction isolation level cannot be used, since obviously you [cannot change the isolation level of an ongoing transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html).

This also means that you need a statement that adds one more record to the table to compensate for the record with `id=5` that was added by transaction A, while transaction B was running. `insert` is ruled out by the question, so that really leaves you with `replace`, since it is the only other statement that can create a new record in a table.

There is another sneaky solution. Issue an

```
update t set b=1 where id=5;
```

and the counts will match. The reason is that the consistent snapshot applies to select only, [but not to changes to data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html). The above statement will update the record with `id=5` and thus brings it into the snapshot:

> The snapshot of the database state applies to SELECT statements within a transaction, not necessarily to DML statements. If you insert or modify some rows and then commit that transaction, a DELETE or UPDATE statement issued from another concurrent REPEATABLE READ transaction could affect those just-committed rows, even though the session could not query them. If a transaction does update or delete rows committed by a different transaction, those changes do become visible to the current transaction.

Also, if you remove the `select` before the `insert` in transaction B, you should get the same result without adding anything on the red dotted line. The consistent snapshot is established by the first read. By removing the mentioned select, the snapshot would be established after transaction A commits, therefore its changes would be visible to transaction B.